# I disconnected my PC for a clean up, and now the screen is not working

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I disconnected my PC for a clean up, and also to change The DVD reader. I trusted myself that i would remember how to connect everything to the motherboard again, but, something is not working well:
I' ve been having some trouble figuring out how to connect the frontal panel cables to the motherboard (power sw, reset, power led, and led + ,led -). Meaning, maybe i have not connected them well yet. But at least i could turn the power on. The hard drive is connected to the power and to the sata, the video, mouse and keyboard are also connected, but the monitor (the screen) does not turn on. I mean, the green  asus message that should appear, just doesn't appear.
Any idea, about what am i doing wrong?[image: This is how the computer looks right now. I know that this image does not help at all]

Comment: Somewhere on the motherboard should be a model number.  If you go to Asus' website, you should be able to search for that motherboard, and download a manual for it.  That will tell you what should plug in where.  For the video, need more info; it sounds like the monitor never even gets a signal? I'm going back to basics, and going to ask if the monitor is plugged in to both power and the video card, and powered on? If so, are there any beeps coming from the motherboard, and if so, how many, and do they repeat? Also, have you tried reseating the video card?

Comment: Thanks for the Tip about the manual. The monitor is plugged to the power and the video card, but it does seem that it never gets a signal When i turn the power on. Also, i Am not hearing beeps of any kind. I don't know how to reset a video card...

Comment: Not reset; re-seat. Take it out, and put it back again, pushing firmly and evenly. Of course, I'm just realizing that you may have on-board video, which means this doesn't apply.  Also, does the power light on both the PC and monitor come on? What color is the light on the monitor, and does it change?

Comment: I guess i have on board video. (I have an audio card that is already seated). There is no light When i turn on the power. There should be a green light. When i turn the monitor on there is a blue light, but since there is no signal it turns yellow..

Comment: Well then yes, it sounds like the PC isn't powering on. It's obviously getting power, since the light on the motherboard is lit, but the switch is either not plugged in right, or broken. Did you find the model number of the motherboard?

Comment: Ok. Yes, it is an ASUS M4N78 PRO.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/au/Motherboards/M4N78_PRO/HelpDesk_Manual/

Comment: The PC light now exists and it is green. No beeps. And the monitor is not working still. You have helped anyway. Thanks

Comment: Switch the power off at the mains but leave it plugged in. Remove the CMOS battery for 10 minutes [coin-shaped thing, silver, just above the red SATA cable.] Put it back, boot, reset BIOS settings if necessary.

Comment: I just did that, but The screen is not showing anything